# Where are the type names defined?

Tags: c#, types

When you get Type of the variable you can check its name:

```
if (my_type.Name=="Int32")
```

however it would more elegant to write

```
if (my_type.Name==TypeNames.Int32)
```

to avoid typos. I can define such class on my own, but maybe there is already definition somewhere?

If yes, where?

---

**Note**: please avoid wondering "why would you like to get type of the variable in the first place", "it is better to use 'is'" and alike. Thank you very much!

---

**Edit**: meanwhile, I jumped into the conclusion it would be enough to ignore the type of the object (my_type variable) and check the object instead. In other words the my_type is not necessary. I forgot about null case :-( Less code, more sleep, that's what I need ;-)

Comment: why don't to check a type itself? 
if( my_type ==typeof(int))

Comment: If you want answers which don't ask obvious questions, you should *answer* those questions rather than just saying not to ask them. Otherwise we won't know *why* the normal approach isn't approach for you.

Comment: @macias how come? both of them GetType and typeof return Type which you can compare.

Comment: `GetType` isn't equivalent to `typeof`, but that doesn't make `if (my_type == typeof(int))` wrong

Comment: @Arseny, @Tim, you are completely right, I spotted that and deleted my comments :-) Sorry for messing up. @Jon, with all respect I beg to differ. It is matter of time (it is quicker to ask, than to unfold whole story), IMHO there is too much wondering on the net, and less solid information. But if you are still curious :-) I get array of objects with array of types, and then I have to process them.

Comment: If such a global class existed, it would have to have all the names of types in the program, including the ones you made up. The closest would be to ask an assembly for its types, then ask their names, though the order of Assembly.GetTypes() is not known, so you probably need the type's name to find the type you want.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try the following

```
typeof(Int32).Name
```

If you want to compare types though doing so by name is not the best solution as it will be wrong in many cases.  It's more correct to compare the types directly.

```
if ( m_type == typeof(Int32) ) { 
  ...
}
```

Comment: I marked you comment as answer to my question, because it is very nice, but just out curiosity I am still interested in getting "real" answer to my question. Thank you again.

Comment: @macias: The simple answer your exact question is, "No, there isn't such a class - because there doesn't need to be."

Comment: But this *is* the real answer to your question... Q: "Where are the type names defined?" A: "In the Type.Name property"

Comment: @Jon, thank you. That is the answer to the question. @Tim, that's not I meant, I was looking for string constant set. The above is perfect solution for me though.

Answer (score 2):

The type names are not defined anywhere in a class. They are generated at runtime by the CLR (by a call to the external `ConstructName` function) using reflection.

Using the suggestion of JaredPar will do the job.

Comment: They are stored somewhere: in the assembly metadata. The way you access this metadata is through the `Type` class.

Comment: @Tim Robinson: Surely, they must be stored somewhere. I was missing some essential bits... not enough coffee yet ;-)